# Copying all of model's children. Skip those that have a foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am adding a feature to an existing application (which I id not make). I am trying to make a method which copies a Report over to a new Period. The Report model has lots of children called Responses, some of these have foreign keys.

Here is my copy method, in the Report model:

```
def copy(new_period)
  copy = self.dup
  copy.report_id = Report.maximum(:report_id).next
  copy.period_id = new_period
  copy.responses = self.responses.map { |response| response.dup }
  copy.save
end
```

This works until you hit a response with a foreign key, then you get:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::Error: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "responses_publication_author_id_key"
```

Is there anyway I can just skip copying all those children that have foreign keys without just catching the exception? These children don't need to be copied.

I hope I am making sense, as I am new to a lot of these concepts. Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
copy.responses = self.responses.keep_if({ |response| response.author_id.blank? }).map { |response| response.dup }
```

> [keep_if { |item| block } → ary](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-keep_if)
>
> Deletes every element of self for which the given block evaluates to false.
>
> See also [#select!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-select-21)
>
> If no block is given, an Enumerator is returned instead.